# Sending an e-mail with multiple attachments?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, email

This is probably a silly question, but I really need some advice.
I'm an undergraduate student and I want to take a different major in grad school. Luckily, my university offers you a possibility to take a different major in grad school provided that you pass certain exams and show that you'll be able to follow the program. Now, I've sent an e-mail to a professor that's in charge of all that at the department that I want to get into, and he said that for a start I should send him the list of all the courses I've taken with corresponding grades.

Now I don't know if I should write it manually (so it's going to be a really really long e-mail) or if I should take screenshots from this "program" we use at university that contains all the information about my academic success? For this second option, I'm worried it might seem impolite to just send multiple attachments and I know some people don't even open attachments because they're afraid of malware...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check if the program has an option to print a grade overview (as PDF). Most programs have, including the option to verify the correctness of grades on the university homepage somehow. Just typing it in a mail, you can, in theory, make up anything.

Comment: Is there an official transcript, or a single document containing all of your grades which you could obtain from the university's virtual learning environment (e.g. Blackboard)?

Comment: @Dirk No, it doesn't have anything like that, it's a very primitive program. I can't even print the page from my browser, it mixes everything up...

Comment: Oh wow. So you don't get any kind of official transcript except the final certificate? Then the prof surely is aware of these problems and I would go with Buffy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about the actual number of attachments, you can put all your screenshots in a text document and then export it as a pdf, for example. That makes it more clear than multiple attachments.

Otherwise, I would also suggest to write the list down manually as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I just thought of the same thing. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you really are stuck in this dilemma and there is no technical solution, then you can do both. Provide your own typed summary *and* attach the evidence as attachments. But give a warning that the attachments are just the proof and add no additional content.

Then the person can look at the attachments or not.

But commenters have suggested other, technical, solutions that might be better.

Answer (score 2):

> he said...I should send him the list of all the courses I've taken with corresponding grades

That's a bizarre requirement, he should have access to that information.

> I don't know if I should write it manually

I suggest you **write it manually**, as you have suggested. In addition, **offer to send screenshots as supporting evidence**, should that be required.

> I'm worried it might seem impolite to just send multiple attachments

My approach leaves the decision to the professor.

Comment: No, it's not bizarre, at my uni professors don't have access to that information... Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @lmc Employees should have access to information needed to do their jobs. This isn't the case here, which is unusual.